# GIven a tree, for each vertex find longest path to other vertex

Tags: tree, dynamic-programming

So i have a problem stated as above.
I'm thinking of some dp but im not really good at it...

Example:
5 vertexes,
connected pairs:
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)

answer for each vertex (and path):
1: 2 (1-3-4)
2: 3 (2-1-3-4)
3: 2 (3-1-2)
4: 3 (4-3-1-2)
5: 3 (5-3-1-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming undirected tree.

If you want for each vertex *v* to explicitly find the longest path that begin at *v* you are good with BFS/DFS starting at each vertex because the summation of longest paths could up to n<sup>2</sup> (a degenerated tree like a line or branch if you like to call it that way). As memory consumption is a lower bound of every algorithm then your algorithm's running time will be Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) in worst case scenario.

If you only want the values of the longest paths i recommend you read [this post](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/79857) about dynamic programming on trees, specifically the solution to problem **Tree Distances I** as it's identical to what you ask for. There is even an [explanation](https://youtu.be/N7e4CTfimkU) in YouTube and an [accepted code example](https://github.com/kartik8800/CSES/blob/master/Tree%20Distances%201) in c++.